# node.js sybase driver

Tags: node.js, sap-ase

I am developing an app using node.js express framework and would need to connect to sybase ASE database. I did enough search and couldn't find the sybase driver for node.js. doesn't node.js support sybase or should I use something like a generic driver?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An exhaustive list of database drivers is on the node.js wiki here:

https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Modules#wiki-database

But no Sybase so that leaves using an ODBC driver which, if on `*nix`, then you have the option of:

https://github.com/w1nk/node-odbc

Alternatively, Sybase ASE has it's own [web services engine](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc10061.1570/html/wbsrvcs/BHCEGAEG.htm) which exposes SQL and stored procedures through a SOAP API. Your best option may be to just roll your own SOAP client in node against that API, perhaps using [node-soap](https://github.com/milewise/node-soap).

Answer (score 3):

As of 2015, a non-odbc implementation based on Jconnect is available. It requires Java.

You can install it with

```
npm install sybase
```

More info:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sybase

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been a while, but if you are still looking, try this:

https://www.npmjs.org/package/sqlanywhere

Comment: This is a "link-only answer". As that page might go away, please add at least a summary to your answer.

Comment: Your link is for Sybase SQL Anywhere database where as the requirement is for Sybase ASE database

Answer (score 0):

node.js comes with no DB support at all.

DB connectors are out of the scope of the node.js distribution. But the cummunity fills the gap here e.g. for mysql there is [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql).

Problem here is that you want to use a DB without a big (open source) community, so, after some googeling, there is no node.js connector.

If you want to create a connector for sybase ASE you might have a look at node-mysql to get startet. But this is nothing you do in one weekend.